# SQL Server something like foreach

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have view with colums
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ1Cw.png)
[image]

Now I want TOP 2 elements for every ShipRegion. 
I used query like this

```
SELECT Region, CustomerID, SUM(ExtendedPrice) AS Price 
FROM Invoices 
GROUP BY CustomerID, Region 
ORDER BY Region, Price DESC;
```

That query generates values like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6jVA.png)
[image]

Now I need chose only 2 biggest values for every region.

Comment: What is `Cena` in your ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Sorry i forget to change on "Price" I used non English names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select rc.*
from (select region, customerid, sum(extendedPrice) as price,
             row_number() over (partition by region order by sum(extendedprice) desc) as seqnum
      from invoices
      group by region, customerid
     ) rc
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: I wish my teacher showed me partition. It's awesome.

Comment: @DonQnei . . . I introduce it before `JOIN`, when I teach SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the incorrect way about doing this.

try something like this.

```
WITH cte AS 
    SELECT 
        Region
        , CustomerID
        , SUM(ExtendedPrice) AS Price 
        , ROW_NUMBER over( Region , CustomerID, SUM(ExtendedPrice) ) ORDER BY SUM(ExtendedPrice) DESC as 'row_number'
    FROM 
        Invoices 
    GROUP BY 
        CustomerID
        , Region 
    ORDER BY 
        Region
        , Cena DESC

SELECT 
    region 
FROM 
    cte
GROUP BY 
    region
    , value
HAVING 
    row_number < 2
```

Also, SQL Server naively supports FOR loops. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-for-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

This will allow you to specify a clause and iterate over it as you would expect.